# Solution for meteor/npm issue - syntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.

Tags: meteor, npm

I've been having a documented error using meteor with a package (multichain-node) that uses a later version of node - see here https://forums.meteor.com/t/so-i-cant-use-es6-with-meteor-1-3-afterall-update-got-it-working/21019.

There are a few solutions I've seen written about and I would appreciate advice as to the easiest path forward:
1. Fork the package and try to make it compatible with meteor (e.g., not use const and let)
2. Wrap it in a meteor package
3. Look into transpiling...

Any thoughts or other ideas? I'm trying to avoid going down an endless rabbit hole

Comment: You can try Meteor 1.4 (currently in beta), which might solve solve the problem (it uses node v4).

Comment: You can also bundle your app and run it with node 4 or 5. Once bundled and unpacked, it no longer requires you to use the specific node version meteor uses internally. You will probably need to reinstall the fiber npm package when you do that, but it worked for me with a different node 5 npm package.

Comment: could u find a solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39794780/ionic2-white-screen-error-on-deploy-android-4-2-2-use-of-const-in-strict-mode